# How to format variables using Python

Tags: python

I'm having issues formatting my variables. My PORT1 and PORT2 are not working properly. I'm getting syntax errors. What I'm doing wrong.  Thank you for the inputs.

```
import socket
import os
import netifaces
NICS = netifaces.interfaces()
PORT1 = NICS[1]
PORT2 = NICS[2]
os.system("nmcli con add type team-slave con-name team0-port1 ifname {}".format(PORT1)) master team0)
os.system("nmcli con add type team-slave con-name team0-port2 ifname {}".format(PORT2)) master team0)
```

Error:

```
os.system("nmcli con add type team-slave con-name team0-port1 ifname {}".format(PORT1)) + master team0)
                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `master team0` is syntax error. What is the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem that you are trying to append string `master team0` but you didn't wrap that in quotes also there one more closing bracket than opening ones

I thin this is what it should be

```
os.system("nmcli con add type team-slave con-name team0-port1 ifname {} master team0".format(PORT1))
```

Comment: Thank you, with the help. The new formatting it's a little confusing sometimes.